# banner and Xtender shortcut keys

Tags: database, query

I work for a university and use banner (Version 8) and Xtender. I am looking for shortcut keys for 'Query results' and 'new query' ? I was not able to find good documentation referring to shortcut keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further research, there is no hot-key shortcut mapped for these 2 specific functions under the Banner 8 implementation. Perhaps this may change under implementation of upgrade to Banner 9.